# SCDF task restarting automaticalling after few minutes when the request is failed

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am using SCDF 2.7.1, Which is using postgres db (used in company).

Now the question is, if we try to launch composed task , it is giving undefined error sometimes, (ie) it failed to launch . After that we will again try to launch. Then it was successful.

The issue is that, the same task is relaunching automatically after 15-20 minutes.Because of this automatic launch, same task is triggering twice.  We are suspecting that is there any relaunch option if there is any launch failed? Or any restart policy applied?

Thanks for any information in  advance.

We are expecting is there there any changes in deployment.yaml file to avoid relaunch the task once the launch gets failed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In which environment are you launching the task? 
CloudFoundry and Kuberenetes will try multiple times to start an application until it reports that it is running.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest upgrading to 2.9.x or 2.10.x since 2.7.x isn't supported anymore.